# Updating a specific row in csv file

Tags: python, csv, row

I have a csv file like this:

```
Name,PhoneNumber,Adress
```

I want to get input from the user and change the name. I can delete the whole row.

```
name = input("Enter a name : ")
fieldnames = ["name", "number", 'address']
with open('book.csv', 'r') as csvfile, open('outputfile.csv', 'w') as output:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    for row in reader:
        if not name == row['name']:
            writer.writerow({'name': row['name'], 'number': row['number'], 'address': row['address']})
shutil.move('outputfile.csv','book.csv')
```

This is my deleting code.

Comment: `row['name'] == input("enter new name:")` when name matches. then write row. is that what you want?

Comment: Yes write the row with the new name.

Comment: As an aside, you could just do `writer.writerow(row)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if name matches, just interactively prompt for a new name, updating `row`:

```
for row in reader:
    if name == row['name']:
        row['name'] = input("enter new name for {}".format(name))
    # write the row either way
    writer.writerow({'name': row['name'], 'number': row['number'], 'address': row['address']})
```

Aside: for maximum compatibility (specially on windows), python 2 needs `open('outputfile.csv', 'wb')` (or you get blank lines in output file) and python 3 needs `open('outputfile.csv', 'w', newline='')`.