# Writing back the updated dataframe to csv file in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv loaded using pandas as a dataframe.
I make a update to only one record of the dataframe and write back to the original csv file. I know that in order to write back we have to write the whole dataframe back to csv.

like this:

```
df1.to_csv(file_name)
```

However, is there any where we can write back the updated values alone to the csv instead of writing the whole file?

Please advise

Comment: Why do you want to write the file after every update ? Can't you make some fix number of updates and then write the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-to-modify-a-text-file)

Comment: @ManishSaraswat - It will get updated only once during a process and i need to write back only once in csv, But still, i assume that if there are millions of records, for updating one single value i will be using system resources of writing millions of records

Comment: You cannot do that with pandas. You need to keep track of affected lines and update them separately. That said, I think your actual solution is using a database.

Comment: @ayhan there could be very real use case where you have to update a fraction of file and db can't be used there

Comment: I recommend you look up HDFStore, e.g. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.HDFStore.append.html. This can be converted easily into a `pandas` dataframe in memory if required.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating a specific row in csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574037/updating-a-specific-row-in-csv-file)

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I highly doubt that there is a use case where you have tabular data so you can use pandas but you *cannot* use a db.

Comment: they can use a db if they don't want to processing, but in this case I am pretty sure that OP is doing some data processing step by step. You can look more at some frameworks like spark, dask etc if you are unsure about the usecase. @ayhan

Comment: @ArpitSolanki pandas loads data into memory. So spark and dask are irrelevant here. Processing happens *after* you read data. You provide no case where you have to read data from a flat file instead of a db.